# Computation of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, additive-combinatorics

**NOTATIONS.**

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We define the sets $\mathfrak{M}_{0}:=\emptyset$ and
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{M}_{n}&:=\left\{m=\left(m_{1},m_{2},\ldots,m_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{n}\mid1m_{1}+2m_{2}+\ldots+nm_{n}=n\right\}&\forall n\geq1
\end{align}
and we use the notations:
\begin{align}
m!&:=m_{1}!m_{2}!\ldots m_{n}!,&|m|&:=m_{1}+m_{2}+\ldots+m_{n}.
\end{align}

**QUESTION.**

I want to evaluate or just bound with respect to $n$ the series
\begin{align}
S_{n}&:=\sum_{m\in\mathfrak{M}_{n}}\frac{\left(n+\left|m\right|\right)!}{m!}\ \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(k+1\right)^{-m_{k}}.
\end{align}
My hope is that $S_{n}\leq n!n^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha$ independant of $n$.

**BACKGROUND.**

In order to build an analytic extension from a given real-analytic function, I had to use the Faà di Bruno's formula for a composition (see for example [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)). After some elementary computations, my problem boils down to show the convergence of
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sum_{m\in\mathfrak{M}_{n}}\frac{\left(n+\left|m\right|\right)!}{m!}\ \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(k+1\right)^{-m_{k}}
\end{align}
where $x\in\mathbb{C}$ is such that the complex modulus $|x|$ can be taken as small as desired (in particular, we can choose $|x|<\mathrm{e}^{-1}$ to kill any $n^{\alpha}$ term from the bound on $S_{n}$).

**SOME WORK.**

It is clear that we have to to understand the sets $\mathfrak{M}_{n}$ in order to go on (whence the tag "combinatorics"). So I tried to see what were these sets:

- for $n=2$ :
  \begin{array}{cc}
  2&0\\
  0&1
  \end{array}
- for $n=3$ :
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  3&0&0\\
  1&1&0\\
  0&0&1
  \end{array}
- for $n=4$ :
  \begin{array}{cccc}
  4&0&0&0\\
  2&1&0&0\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  0&2&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  \end{array}
- for $n=5$ :
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
  5&0&0&0&0\\
  3&1&0&0&0\\
  2&0&1&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1&0\\
  1&2&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0&0\\
  \end{array}

Above, each line corresponds to an multiindex $m$, and the $k$-th column is the coefficient $m_{k}$. We see for example that the cardinal of $\mathfrak{M}_{n}$ becomes strictly greater than $n$ if $n\geq5$. Also, because I wanted to reorder the set of summation in $S_{n}$ into a the set of all multiindices $m$ such that $|m|=j$ for $1\leq j\leq n$, I tried to count given $j$ the number of $m$ such that $|m|=j$; when $n=10$, I counted $8$ multiindices $m$ with length $|m|=4$, so that this number can be greater than $n/2$. Another remark is that the number of multiindices $m$ such that $|m|=j$ becomes larger if $j$ is "about" $n/2$ - don't ask me what "about" means here, I just tried some example and saw this phenomenon.

Comment: Here is a suggestion, spurred by a vague recollection of similar work done long ago.  There may be a way to use AM-GM inequality to bound the expression.  I feel optimistic though that alpha will be small.  Gerhard "It's That Time Of Year" Paseman, 2016.12.12.

Comment: (1) By $\mathbb{N}$ you mean **non-negative** integers; (2) The sets $\mathfrak{M}_n$ is just the set of integer partitions of $n$; (3) Your example for $n=2$ has a typo: $2 0$ and $0 1$.

Comment: This is better discussed in the language of integer partitions.  Generating functions may help.  Where did this problem come from?

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thanks for the idea, I will have a try!

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Thanks for the precisions, you're totally right for (1) and (3). As for (2), I know what $\mathfrak{M}_{n}$ is, but I do not really know how use it. Have got any clue?

Comment: @PatDevin You are the second person that has talked about generating functions. But I am not used to use this tool. This problem comes from General Relativity: I need a resolvent estimate for some Schrödinger operator with potentials, and I need to use an analytic extension of the potentials. They depend on a coordinate $r(x)$, and only the expression of $x(r)$ is known: it is here that I use the Lagrange inversion formula to get the above expression with xx (and I want to show that this formula holds for some $x\in\mathbb{C}$, probably $|x|$ small).

Comment: A very good answer has been provided here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049773/computation-of-a-series.

Answer (score 3):

Using $\frac1{k+1}<\frac1k$ and the notation $\sum im_i=\lambda\vdash n$ (equiv. $\lambda\in\mathfrak{M}_n$), begin estimating
\begin{align}
S_{n} 
<&\sum_{m\in\mathfrak{M}_{n}}\frac{\left(n+\left|m\right|\right)!}{m!}\ \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^{-m_{k}}
=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\frac{n!}{m!\prod k^{m_k}}\frac{(n+\vert m\vert)!}{n!}.
\end{align}
Note that $\frac{n!}{m!\prod k^{m_k}}$ is the number of permutations $\pi\in \mathfrak{S}_n$ having cycle type $(m_1,\dots,m_n)$ and $\vert m\vert=\kappa(\pi)=\#$ of cycles in $\pi$. In light of this,
\begin{align}
S_n<\sum_{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\frac{(n+\kappa(\pi))!}{n!}
=\sum_{j=1}^nc(n,j)\frac{(n+j)!}{n!};
\end{align}
where $c(n,j)$ are the (unsigned) [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). On the other hand, the numbers $a_n:==\sum_{j=1}^nc(n,j)(n+1)\cdots(n+j)$ are listed on [OEIS A052819](http://oeis.org/A052819) and there Vaclav Kotesovec provideda growth estimate
$$a_n \qquad \sim \qquad (1+r)^n(2+r)^n\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n.$$
Combining this with [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n$, we obtain
$$\frac1{n+1}\frac{S_n}{n!} \qquad \sim \qquad \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{n+1}
(1+r)^n(2+r)^n$$
where $r=0.794862961852611133\cdot$. Hence, the desired convergence of your series can be achieved form small $x$.

**REMARK.** The above estimates can be improved although it is not necessary for your purpose. For example, there is an [expected number of cycles](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Expected_number_of_cycles_of_permutation_equals_harmonic_number_of_degree) in a permutation (regarding $\kappa(\pi)$) given by 
$$H_n=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n\sim \log n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your $S_n$ starts with $1,1,5,41,469,6889,123605,2620169,64074901,1775623081,54989743445,...$; this seems to be [A032188](http://oeis.org/A032188) on OEIS (number of labeled circular-rooted trees with $n$ leaves). The link contains lots of information if so. In particular, asymptotics given there is $S_{n-1}\sim\frac{n^{n-1}}{2e^n(1-\log(2))^{n-\frac12}}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) $C_m$ of order $m$, in the following form

$$
C_m=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
u_1 &u_2 &\cdots& \cdots &u_{m-1} &u_m \\
1 &0 &\cdots &\cdots &\cdots &0 \\
0 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 &1 &0 \\
\end{array}
\right)_{m \times m} \, .
$$
where $u_1 , u_2, \cdots ,u_m$ are indeterminates. Look at $C_m$ as an adjacency matrix of a weighted digraph. For example, 
the adjacency matrix of  weighted digraph $C_6$ is as shown

[image: adjacency matrix of weighted digraph]

[Chen](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379595901639) has seen the $n$th power of $C_m$ matrix as paths of length $n$  between nodes of weighted digraph. He has proved that

> **Theorem:**
>   Let the $(i,j)$ entry of the $n$th power of matrix $C_m$  called $c_{ij}^n$, then the combinatorial closed-form of $c_{ij}^n$,
>    is in the following form

$$
c_{ij}^n=\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_m)} \frac{k_j+k_{j+1}+\cdots+k_m}{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m}\times
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
k_1+\cdots+k_m \\
k_1,\cdots , k_m
\end{array}
\right)
u_1^{k_1}\cdots u_m^{k_m} \, .
$$
where the summation is over non-negative integers satisfying
$$
k_1+2\, k_2+3\, k_3+\cdots + m\, k_m=n-i+j \, .
$$
and the coefficients $k_i$ are defined $1$ when $n=i-j$.

A simple form of your question is special case of the mentioned theorem when $n=m$, $i=j=1$ and $u_t=\frac{1}{t+1}$, $1\leq t \leq m$. 
With these parameters , we have

$$
c_{11}^m=\sum_{(k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_m)} 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
k_1+\cdots+k_m \\
k_1,\cdots , k_m
\end{array}
\right)
2^{-k_1}\, 3^{-k_2}\, \cdots {(m+1)}^{-k_m} \, .
$$
where the summation is over non-negative integers satisfying
$$
k_1+2\, k_2+3\, k_3+\cdots + m\, k_m=m \, .
$$

For example, when we want to obtain $S_5$, first we should calculate  the $5$th power of matrix $C_5$, 
with $u_t=\frac{1}{t+1}$, $1\leq t \leq 5$, as shown

$$
 C_5={
 \left( \begin {array}{ccccc}
  \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{6}\\ 
  \\
  1&0&0&0&0\\ 
  \\
  0&1&0&0&0\\ 
  \\
  0&0&1&0&0\\ 
  \\
  0&0&0&1&0
  \end {array}
   \right)}^5=
   \left( \begin {array}{ccccc} 
   {\frac {521}{480}}&{\frac {2887}{4320}}&
{\frac {439}{960}}&{\frac {527}{1800}}&{\frac {629}{4320}}\\ 
\\
{\frac {629}{720}}&{\frac {467}{720}}&{\frac {181
}{480}}&{\frac {43}{180}}&{\frac {17}{144}}\\
\\
 {\frac {17}{24}}&{\frac {187}{360}}&{\frac {33}{80}}&\frac{1}{5}&{\frac {7}{72}}\\ 
 \\
 {\frac {7}{12}}&{\frac {5}{12}}&{\frac {13}{40}}
&{\frac {4}{15}}&\frac{1}{12}\\
\\
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{6}
\end {array} \right)
$$

That results that

$$
S_5=c_{11}^5=\frac {521}{480}= 1.085416667\, .
$$

Comment: The coefficients in the question are not multinomials, they are multinomials times $\frac{(n+m_1+...+m_n)!}{(m_1+...+m_n)!}$

Comment: You right. I wanted to show a different attitude to this kind of series. The answer was edited by your tip. Thanks.